# Indenting entire field value in visual studios

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I'm trying to create a report that returns it's value indented if it meets a certain criteria in an iif expression. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean to have the data itself indented or if you want the row to indent for a certain value, but I have a solution for the former issue.  There is a set of properties associated with textboxes that deal with indenting text. There is `HangingIndent`, `LeftIndent`, and `RightIndent`.  If your data is aligned to the left, you can use either `HangingIndent` or `LeftIndent`.

[image: indentImage]

You'll need to put the following expression in whichever indent you require based on the alignment of your data.

```
=IIF([your Condition here], "10pt", "0pt")
```

This will indent the data by 10pt if true and leave the data unindented if false.  I tested it with a simple dataset that pulled an `ID` from 1-9 and set the `HangingIndent` property to indent if the `ID` was equal to 5.

```
=IIF(Fields!id.Value = "5", "10pt", "0pt")
```

Which yielded these results:

[image: imageSample]